# Rails 3.1 Error Catching

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I think Rails 3.1 is changing the way that errors are raised. Can anyone assist or confirm this? I'm attempting to create custom errors pages with Rails 3.1.0.rc1

```
unless config.consider_all_requests_local
    rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_error
    rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :render_not_found
    rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :render_not_found
end
```

^^ This doesn't work.

```
config.consider_all_requests_local       = true
```

That is in my development environment by default. I'm assuming Rails 3.1 removes the "action_controller" but I can't confirm this anywhere.

Thanks!

Comment: What kind of errors? Just exceptions in general?

Comment: It would be helpful if you can post some code and explain what *specifically* what unexpected behaviour you are seeing.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm assuming the following code appears in your ApplicationController?

```
unless config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, :with => :render_error
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, :with => :render_not_found
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, :with => :render_not_found
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, :with => :render_not_found
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, :with => :render_not_found
end
```

If so, try replacing this line:

```
unless config.consider_all_requests_local
```

with this line (pre Rails 3 I think):

```
unless ActionController::Base.consider_all_requests_local
```

or this (post Rails 3):

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
```

Answer (score 9):

I don't believe Matt's solution will catch routing errors in Rails 3.0/3.1.

Try putting the following in your application.rb:

```
# 404 catch all route
config.after_initialize do |app|
  app.routes.append{ match '*a', :to => 'application#render_not_found' } unless config.consider_all_requests_local
end
```

See: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/671#issuecomment-1780159

Worked well for me!

Comment: Thanks for adding this! Learned about it a few weeks after posting my original answer here. :)

Comment: in general things that end up being the equiv. of  if !Rails.env.production are dangerous...

Comment: @Kevin - Where does this happen?  Is this in reference to the use of `consider_all_request_local`?  If so, I don't think you make a valid argument, as this is a setting defined on a per-environment basis.  There are numerous settings configured per-environment, and this is just one of many.

Comment: It's been awhile, but I agree and withdraw my complaint :)