# Testing error pages in Rails with Rspec + Capybara

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec, capybara

In Rails 3.2.9 I have custom error pages defines like this:

```
# application.rb
config.exceptions_app = self.routes

# routes.rb
match '/404' => 'errors#not_found'
```

Which works like expected. When I set `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` in `development.rb` I get the `not_found` view when visiting `/foo`

But how do I test this with Rspec + Capybara?

I've tried this:

```
# /spec/features/not_found_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'not found page' do
  it 'should respond with 404 page' do
    visit '/foo'
    page.should have_content('not found')
  end
end
```

When I run this spec I get:

```
1) not found page should respond with 404 page
  Failure/Error: visit '/foo'
  ActionController::RoutingError:
    No route matches [GET] "/foo"
```

How can I test this?

**Edit:**

Forgot to mention: I've set `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` in `test.rb`

Answer (score 32, accepted):

The problematic setting in the *test.rb* is not only the

```
consider_all_requests_local = false
```

but also

```
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

If you set this you should be able to test the error.
I was not able to use it in an around filter.

Have a look for http://agileleague.com/blog/rails-3-2-custom-error-pages-the-exceptions_app-and-testing-with-capybara/

Comment: Thanks, that was exactly what I was missing. I thought the problem was deeper than that, so I had started digging around in Capybara...

Comment: What about for a controller spec? With these changes my feature specs work fine, but I'm still getting the failed test (with an ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound error) in a controller spec. Is there something I need to do differently for these?

Comment: The link is broken and is now at http://agileleague.com/blog/rails-3-2-custom-error-pages-the-exceptions_app-and-testing-with-capybara/

Comment: If you don't want to set this in the test.rb file you can check this solution
http://stackoverflow.com/a/9941128/2989852

Answer (score 1):

the `config.consider_all_requests_local = false` setting would need to be set in `config/environments/test.rb` in the same way you have done for your development one.

If you don't want to do this for all tests, perhaps an [rspec around filter](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/v/2-0/docs/hooks/around-hooks) would be useful to set the state before the test and restore afterwards like so:

```
# /spec/features/not_found_spec.rb
require 'spec_helper'
describe 'not found page' do
  around :each do |example|
     Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = false
     example.run
     Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = true
  end

  it 'should respond with 404 page' do
    visit '/foo'
    page.should have_content('not found')
  end
end
```

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I already have tried with setting `consider_all_requests_local = false` in `test.rb`.

Comment: For me too, I have ActionController::RoutingError:

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it and don't want to change `config/environments/test.rb`, you can follow the solution from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9941128/2767026).

Answer (score 0):

You can access directly 404 error page:

Visit `/404` instead of `/foo`

Answer (score 0):

The variables from `Rails.application.config` are read at the start of the test suite to a separate hash (`Rails.application.env_config`) - so changing the source variables for a particular spec doesn't work.

I was able to solve this with the following around block - this allows testing the exception rescue without impacting the rest of the test suite

```rb
 around do |example|
    orig_show_exceptions = Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_exceptions']
    orig_detailed_exceptions = Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions']

    Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_exceptions'] = true
    Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions'] = false

    example.run

    Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions'] = orig_detailed_exceptions
    Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_exceptions'] = orig_show_exceptions
  end
```

Answer (score -1):

With Rails 5.2, Capybara 3 I was able to simulate page errors with the following

```
around do |example|
  Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
  example.run
  Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
end

before do
  allow(Person).to receive(:search).and_raise 'App error simulation!'
end

it 'displays an error message' do
  visit root_path
  fill_in 'q', with: 'anything'
  click_on 'Search'
  expect(page).to have_content 'We are sorry, but the application encountered a problem.'
end
```

#### Update

This seems to not always work when running the full test suite. So I had to set `config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true` in `config/environments/test.rb` and remove the around block.