# Why don't the config settings in this before filter alter the test environment's settings?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

**NB this is in the context of Rails 4.0.4**

I'm trying to test that Rails correctly delivers custom error pages.

In order for the test environment to process errors like production though I need to alter its configuration. So in line with the guidance from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9008520/why-consider-all-requests-local-fails-with-rspec-config) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13996259/testing-error-pages-in-rails-with-rspec-capybara) I have created the before and after filters that do this:

```
feature 'Error pages:', focus: true do
  include BaseHelper

    before do
      Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = false
      Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
      load "application_controller.rb"
    end 

    after do
      Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local = true
      Rails.application.config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = false
      load "application_controller.rb"
    end

    scenario "system  should return the correct 404 page" do
      # ...
    end
end
```

However that doesn't seem to affect things. Using only those before filters I can see (using `save_and_open_page`) that the app does not use my error pages.

### I can however alter these settings directly in `environments/test.rb`

If I put the same settings into `test.rb` then the tests do correctly use my custom error pages:

```
# Show full error reports and disable caching
config.consider_all_requests_local       = false
config.action_dispatch.show_exceptions = true
```

**When these settings are in place in the config, the test works as expected and returns the custom error pages.**

*Also, in case it's relevant, in both cases I'm using a custom exceptioins_app handler:*

```
config.exceptions_app = ->(env) { ExceptionController.action(:show).call(env) }
```

### Why aren't the config settings being picked up via the filters?

I don't understand why the exact same changes made in the before filter don't seem to affect the tests.

Comment: It's been my experience that config settings generally require a server restart; I haven't dug into these particular settings to see why, though.

Comment: @DaveNewton in the context of running in the middle of a set of other tests though Dave, how would you trigger the server restart / reload?

Comment: Honestly, I probably wouldn't. What version of Rails are you targeting?

Comment: 4.0.4. I'm going with just setting these permanently in the test.rb file for now. I'm not sure what the potential fallout is but it doesn't seem to affect the other tests so far

Comment: My first assumption would be that the mechanism(s) for altering config values is different since those questions target earlier versions. If you dig into it and figure it out it's definitely worth an answer or blog post, though!

Comment: Thanks Dave - there's a nice carrot :) I'll take a look around...

Comment: How about  playing with `Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_exceptions']` and `Rails.application.env_config['action_dispatch.show_detailed_exceptions']` ?

Comment: @PeterNixey Did you ever find a solution for this? I've just run into the same issue, tried all of the same suggestions here including `env_config['action_dispatch.show_exceptions']` with no luck. Ended up having to do the same thing as you, modding test.rb, which is fine except it makes it rather difficult trying to debug test failures, so end up having to switch it off and on regularly.